# Menu recolher ao clicar no link (nav filho)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Boa tarde, possuo um menu que gostaria que ao clicar no nav-filho o mesmo sumisse voltando ao comportamento inicial.
uso o exemplo de menu do site: admin lte v3: https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/widgets.html

```
 <div class="sidebar">
                <nav class="nav-collapse-hide-child">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                        <li class="nav-item nav-pai">
                            <span></span>
                            <a href="#"  class="nav-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-history"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Ultimos Acessos
                                    <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview nav-pai-list" id="recents" runat="server">
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                                <li class="nav-item nav-pai">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
                                        <p>
                                            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        </p>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview nav-pai-list">
                                           
                                                <li class="nav-item nav-mae">
                                                    <span></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-minus nav-icon"></i>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview nav-mae-list">
                                                           
                                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-filho">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                                                        <p></p>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <aside id="sidezao" class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary" style="background: linear-gradient( #153f73, #2b363a) !important;">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <nav class="nav-collapse-hide-child">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                        
                       
                                <li class="nav-item nav-pai">
                                    <span ></span>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                        <i class=''></i>
                                        <p>
                                         
                                            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        </p>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview nav-pai-list">
                                       
                                           
                                                <li class="nav-item nav-mae">
                                                    <span ></span>
                                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-minus nav-icon"></i>
                                                        <p>
                                                         
                                                            <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-treeview nav-mae-list">
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-filho">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                                                        <p><%# Eval("menu") %></p>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </li>
                                                           
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                         
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                           
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </aside>
```